# Kolmogorov extension theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I have attached to this post a short treatment of the Kolmogorov extension theorem for measures.

In the following, I did not understand what is meant by the $A$ that I circled in red. I suppose that $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}:=\prod^{\infty}_{i=1}\mathbb{R}_i$, but I cannot believe that $A$ is just some subset of this set, i.e. $A$ should be measurable or open or something like that. But on the other hand, I don't if we are talking here about the canonical product topology inducing our notion of measurability on $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}.$  Thus, I am wondering whether anybody could clarify a bit the nature of $A$? 
[image]

Comment: $A$ should be measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$.

Comment: ... which coincides with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the product topology